# 3D Polygons in Python

Tags: python, 3d, polygon

As far as I am aware there is no inbuilt polygon functionality for Python. I want to create a 3D map and figured that polygons would be the best way to go about it.

Not wanting to reinvent the wheel I did some googling and found that there's a lot of Python stuff out there, but I couldn't find what I wanted. Thus before I reinvent the wheel (or invent it a whole), does anybody know of a Polygon system for Python?

Note that it does need to be 3D (I found quite a few 2D ones). Note also that I am not interested in the displaying of them but in storing them and the datastructure within Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most complete geography/mapping systems available for Python that I know about is [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/).  This works on top of the [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), an MVC framework.  With it comes a large collection of polygon, line and distance calculation tools that can even take into account the curvature of the earth's surface if need be.

With that said, the quickest way I can think of to produce a 3D map is using a height map.  Create a two dimensional list of tuples containing (x, y, z) coordinates.  Each tuple represents an evenly spaced point on a grid, mapped out by the dimensions of the array.  This creates a simple plane along the X and Z axes; the ground plane.  The polygons that make up the plane are quads, a polygon with four sides.

Next, to produce the three dimensional height, simply give each point a Y value.  This will create peaks and valleys in your ground plane.

How you render this will be up to you, and converting your grid of points into a polygon format that something like OpenGL can understand may take some work, but have a look at [Visual Python](http://vpython.org/), its the simplest 3D library I've seen for Python.

Comment: This is both a good way of storing it and a system that'll work better for me

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean Polyhedron, not Polygon .. and you might wanna look at [vpython](http://vpython.org/)

Answer (score 0):

CGAL is a C++ geometry library which, amongst other things, models Polyhedra (3D flat-surfaced shapes)

It has Python bindings available. The documentation for the Polygon3 class is here:
http://cgal-python.gforge.inria.fr/Manual/CGAL.Polyhedron.html#Polyhedron_3